# Why I always get "Access Denied" or Timeout error while scrapping https://www.makemytrip.com/ or https://www.tanishq.co.in/?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am not able to scrape these websites.
[Make My Trip](https://www.makemytrip.com/)
[Tanishq](https://www.tanishq.co.in/)

Here is my code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request_headers = {
            "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'X-Crawlera-Profile': 'pass',
            'X-Crawlera-Cookies': 'disable',
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile':'?0',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            "Dnt": "1",
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate,br",
            'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
            }
try:

    response = requests.get('https://makemytrip.com/',headers=request_headers,timeout=20,stream=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    print(str(soup))
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as t:
    print(str(t))
    print ("Timeout occurred")
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

I tried with Selenium too. Then also I can't scrape these websites.
What might be the problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could try removing or increasing the `timeout` argument, but then it could take just about forever. Also, I think the pages are dynamic, so I doubt the fetched HTML will have all the info you want. If you *"tried with Selenium too"* - can you include that code as well? I did a quick test with [this function](https://pastebin.com/VLZ2vPYK) to get `soup` and it looked ok. I used `soup.select('a[href]')` to get the links on the pages and there were 18 from makemytrip and 298 from tanishq....what issues did you face with selenium?